# Create a list with repeated values with list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Say a list `a = [4, 8, 5, 7, 7, 7, 7, 3, 2, 2, 2, 5, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]` is there a way to create this list with list comprehension?

a = [4, 8, 5, (4 times 7), 3, (3 times 2), 5, (5 times 3)]

I know how to do it with just one repeated value, but not three and non-repeated values in between.

Comment: I dont understand your point. The input is the first form, and you want to have the second as output - or vice versa?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are trying to create a literal list from hard-coded counts, then this is far easier achieved by concatenation:

```
a = [4, 8, 5] + 4 * [7] + [3] + 3 * [2] + [5] + 5 * [3]
```

If you must use a list comprehension, you'll have to include a multiplier for each of the values, then use a double loop to repeat the values:

```
# list of (count, value) pairs
inputs = [(1, 4), (1, 8), (1, 5), (4, 7), (1, 3), (3, 2), (1, 5), (5, 3)]
a = [i for count, i in inputs for _ in range(count)]
```

Demo:

```
>>> [4, 8, 5] + 4 * [7] + [3] + 3 * [2] + [5] + 5 * [3]
[4, 8, 5, 7, 7, 7, 7, 3, 2, 2, 2, 5, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
>>> inputs = [(1, 4), (1, 8), (1, 5), (4, 7), (1, 3), (3, 2), (1, 5), (5, 3)]
>>> [i for count, i in inputs for _ in range(count)]
[4, 8, 5, 7, 7, 7, 7, 3, 2, 2, 2, 5, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
```